# Do something when the DOM is completly loaded with ember

Tags: javascript, jquery, ember.js

I'm working with an Ember `2.1.0` application. I want to apply JQuery Steps when the dom is ready. When I do this :

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  trigger: function() {
    console.log($('#subscription-form').length);
  }.on('init')
});
```

This code show a length of 0. When I do it later, the length is 1.

Can I trigger something when the dom completly loaded? Something similar as `$(document).ready` in JQuery?

Should I use a component? What are best practices? Is there something somewhere in the documentation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create another component and run jQuery in its `didInsertElement` hook or you could try:

```
trigger: function() {
  Ember.run.scheduleOnce('afterRender', this, function() {
    console.log($('#subscription-form').length);
  });
}.on('init')
```

Comment: So use a component is a good practice, event for simple things?

Comment: Thanks for your help. It's the second time you helped me today. Many thanks!

Comment: It seems the event is triggered 8 times. Is there a way to trigger it only once? I can't find the documentation on the Ember guide.

Comment: You can have a boolean in your code to make your code run only once.

Comment: You're right but it's trigger even if the component is not ready. 5 times, the length is 0 and 2 times, the length is 1. I just want to trigger it the last time.

Comment: I found the solution with a boolean, as you said, but it's uggly. I can't believe there is no other way.

Comment: Cant you just add $dom ready hook to application controller before extended controller class?

Comment: Use the `didRender` lifecycle hook instead if you're on Ember 1.13+.